# LXC integration and auto-scaling with Mesos

Tags: django, docker, mesos, lxc, marathon

Whereever I am looking for LxC integration with Mesos, I am getting DOCKER + MESOS
or DOCKER + MESOS + MARATHON.
No where there is to find a tutorial about LxC integration with Mesos and auto-scaling.

I was trying to deploy

1. nginx           - LxC Centos 6 - container-nginx
2. python + django - LxC Ubuntu   - container-dj
3. mysql           - LxC Centos 6 - container-mysql
4. redis           - LxC Centos 6 - container-redis

I know that now I am to use Mesos Slave to integrate the LxC, but I am not able to find out how to integrate LxC to Mesos and the austoscale and test HA.

All the answers are pointing to DOCKER this and that.

Answer (score 0):

I think Mesos doesn't support LXC right now, feel free to file a request [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS/).